# Two questions which are exactly the same

Tags: discussion, questions

Today when I was browsing the Main site(ELL), I saw a very strange thing. There are two question which are **exactly** the same!!! Note that I say **exactly the same**, it's not just a duplicate, it's exactly the same!!!

The first one:

Link: [Differences between "indemnity", "remuneration", and "redress"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316385/differences-between-indemnity-remuneration-and-redress)
Poster: [sandmanponderer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/156365/sandmanponderer)

The second one:

Link: [Any differences between "indemnity", "remuneration", and "redress"? These seem the same to me](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/316558/any-differences-between-indemnity-remuneration-and-redress-these-seem-t)
Poster: [omniforce](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/156563/omniforce)

I was really amazed at that time. The definitions and the examples are all the same!!! Can anyone explain this eccentric phenomenon? Here are what I guess:

**Explanation #1:**

The first post is posted on 6/1, and the second one is posted on 6/3. The first post hasn't received any answer. So maybe the first poster created another account, and asked the same question to draw more attention.

**Explanation #2:**

The second poster joined ELL later than the first poster. So maybe he wants to ask a question, but doesn't know what he can ask. Hence, he just copied the first question.

**Explanation #3:**

Coincidence???

I can't think of any explanations. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report. I can't tell whether that is the same person who lost access to their account or not. Moderators can close questions as duplicates, even if the target has no answer, so in the future you can also raise a custom flag on the question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that in the future(I'm flag-banned now).